# Is there a version of CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA that can be seen by more than one user on windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-10, appdata

I need to have a technician install some files into a folder on some desktops (not the documents folder or Program files) that can later be overwritten by a program running on the PC using an envionment variable to point to the correct folder.

The old local\appsdata would be fine for this but under windows 8 onwards the environment variable FOLDERID_LocalAppData refers to %LOCALAPPDATA% (%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local.

This seems to imply that if the technician is logged on (probably with an admin account) to put the files there in the first place, then when he logs off and another user logs on the %USERPROFILE% will be different and the files unavailable to the new user.

Is this correct? If so where can the technician install these files so that they can be read/deleted/ overwritten ect by any user logged onto that PC. ie which environment varaible should my program use?

Comment: FOLDERID_LocalAppData has *always* been per-user.  You probably want FOLDERID_ProgramData.  (Folder IDs aren't environment variables, by the way, even though the documentation describes them in terms of the corresponding environment variables.)

Comment: I think FOLDERID_ProgramData refers to C:\ProgramData. Is that open for programable read/write/delete by any user? (I don't have access to the machines where this will run so I can't test these things in advance)

Comment: Yes, with caveats.  The Program Data folder allows any user to create files and subfolders.  However, any file or subfolder that is created will by default give write access only to the user who created it.  So in your scenario you need to make sure to set explicit permissions for any new files or folders you create.